# Unfortunately, (app name) has stopped - Android development error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, emulation

I am learning to develop Android applications and have come across a problem in my first project. I am following a tutorial (Derek Banas) to create an app that will allow the user to type in some text, hit a button and then the app will output that text.
I have written the code and have recieved no errors, but whenever I run the app on the emulator, it says "Unfortunately, (app name) has stopped.
Here is the log cat:

```
08-23 17:51:36.026: D/AndroidRuntime(800): Shutting down VM
08-23 17:51:36.063: W/dalvikvm(800): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x414c4700)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.nick.android.nick/com.nick.android.nick.MainActivity}:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #12: You must supply a layout_height    attribute.
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #12: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5820)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5988)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1831)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1743)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:757)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.nick.android.nick.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from your `MainActivitys` method `setContentView(...).`

The XML layout file you are setting for your Activity contains a view that does not have a `layout_height` property. `layout_height` and `layout_width` are required on every view.

This information is available in the LogCat excerpt you posted:

`08-23 17:51:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(800): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #12: You must supply a layout_height attribute.`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have added the layout_height property to the activity_main.xml file and it works perfectly, thank you.